# Empty JSON vs null conversions to a

Tags: java, json, jersey, put, jooq

I'm trying to create an HTTP PUT endpoint in Java that takes in a `delta json` from the front end and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to implement "nulls".

For example if we have a database model that looks like

```
id : 1
firstname : Luke
lastname : Xu
age : 24
fav_color : Red
```

And we send over a `PUT request to /person/1` with a json of `{age : 25}`. Currently, I have a JOOQ pojo to converts to following JSON to a java model but the problem is it is also updating my database values to be null.

There's no difference between

```
{age : 25}
```

and

```
{id : 1,
firstname : null,
lastname : null,
age : 25,
fav_color : null}
```

Once it hits my Java end point the java model just sets both cases to "null" and there's no difference between a passed in null or the value wasn't being passed in at all.

I also considered processing an input stream (type JSON) but the problem with this is that our JSON names have to be named exactly the same as the database column names which is also kind of unreasonable.

What is the standard for editing the database if we only want to send a "delta json"????

Comment: I believe that it's a question specific for the JSON parsing library you use. I think that you use some kind of ORM which embeds JSONs into your data model. It either supports distinguishing between "value absent" and "value is null" or not. The JSON parsing library I saw had a special value (like JsonNull) for null values. What do you use for parsing?

Comment: You can use a DTO, then retrieve the database entity object, and just update it with the DTO data. DTOs are a pretty common practice. But generally with PUT, all the fields should be included in the request JSON. PUT is generally a _complete_ update. Partial updates are done with PATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jOOQ, I'd suggest you directly pass the JSON values to the jOOQ [`UpdatableRecord`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html), which can in fact distinguish between:

- `null` meaning not initialised (or `default`)
- `null` meaning `null`

It does so by maintaining a [`changed()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed-org.jooq.Field-) flag for each individual column.

For instance:

```
{age : 25}
```

... translates to this Java code:

```java
// record.set(USER.ID, 1) I suspect this is still necessary...?
record.set(USER.AGE, 25);
record.update();
```

... and to this SQL statement:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET age = 25
WHERE id = 1
```

whereas

```
{id : 1,
firstname : null,
lastname : null,
age : 25,
fav_color : null}
```

... translates to this Java code

```java
record.set(USER.ID, 1);
record.set(USER.FIRSTNAME, null);
record.set(USER.LASTNAME, null);
record.set(USER.AGE, 25);
record.set(USER.FAV_COLOR, null);
```

... and to this SQL statement

```sql
UPDATE users
SET firstname = null,
    lastname = null,
    age = 25,
    fav_color = null
WHERE id = 1
```